# Number to string with fixed length

Tags: c++, string

Is there a function in the standard library that would work like `std::to_string`, but with a fixed length?

```
std::cout << formatted_time_string << ":" << std::to_string(milliseconds) << " ... other stuff" << std::endl;
```

In the example above, milliseconds would range from 1 to 3 digits and therefore the output would be improperly formatted.

*I know there are a lot of other options how to do this (e.g. `sprintf`, calculating the length etc.), but an inline option would be nice to have.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use setw() to format the output.

```
std::out << setw(3) << formatted_time_string << ":" << std::to_string(milliseconds)
```

Comment: A combination of `std::setw(3)` and `std::setfill('0')` was exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [`std::setw()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setw/) function to set the field with to use during the output operation. To keep a correct alignement, you can use [`std::setfill()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setfill/) :

```
#include <iomanip>    // for std::setw and std::setfill

std::cout << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(3) << formatted_time_string << ":" << std::to_string(milliseconds) << " ... other stuff" << std::endl;
//        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If `milliseconds` is a `float`, you can also use [`std::setprecision`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/) :

```
#include <iomanip>    // for std::setprecision

std::cout << formatted_time_string << ":" << std::setprecision(3) << milliseconds << " ... other stuff" << std::endl;
//                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: I just checked, `std::setprecision()` seems to have no impact on integers, only on decimals.

Comment: @AdamS that's right, then you should use `std::setw` and `std::setfill`.

Comment: @AdamS I updated my answer too, to add an example of `setfill`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not in [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/format/doc/format.html) way ?

```
#include<boost/format.hpp>

 std::cout << boost::format("%s: %03d :%s\n") 
               % formatted_time_string % milliseconds % " ... other stuff";
```

Answer (score 0):

above methods okay, but something is not satisfied for me.

so, i use this code for my project.

```
wchar_t milliseconds_array[64] = { 0 };
_snwprintf_s(milliseconds_array, sizeof(milliseconds_array), L"%03d", milliseconds);
std::wstring  milliseconds_str = milliseconds_array;
```